# can't install mmmagic with npm install

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, npm

I want to install module mmmmagic in my projet using `npm install mmmgic`, I come across the following error

[image]

Comment: What does that say in English (sorry, I don't know French)?

Answer (score 0):

You either don't have MSVC installed or your build environment isn't set up properly. If you do have MSVC installed, you might try using one of the special VS201x Command Prompts and executing your `npm install mmmagic` from there instead.